# Calling an external mindict.exe file into Java project

Tags: java, import, external, executable

How can I use the Minutiae Extractor (Mindict.exe) provided by NIST in my Java Application. I want to extract minutiae using mindict.exe, Actually I want the solution about what will be the code or which class can I use to call an external .exe file in my Java program.

Note: - I have not written code for this till time.

Comment: Try googling "call an external .exe file in my Java".  Test one of the solutions and then come back with a more specific problem.  Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  The first point is search and research

Comment: Hi Pete, Thanks for the valuable response, I have gone through the google things, actually my problem is that I have minutiae created already, I just wanted to validate the same with the help of that file. I thought Stackoverflow will be the best option for me.